# Why is a list showing empty after I have populated it?

Tags: python, python-3.7

I populate list2 with a while loop. However I encountered inconsistencies in the result. On printing the list, I find that it is empty.
On the contrary list1 has been perfectly populated using identical code

```
k = 0

dark_color = [22, 104, 102, 56, 38, 38, 73, 7, 7]
list1 = []
while k < len(dark_color):
        sum1 = dark_color[k] + dark_color[k+1] + dark_color[k+2]
        list1.append(sum1)
        k = k+3
print(list1)
list1.sort()
myInt = 3
average1 = [x / myInt for x in list1]

light_color = [25, 163, 159, 139, 95, 95, 145, 13, 13]
list2 = []
while k < len(light_color):
        sum2 = light_color[k] + light_color[k+1] + light_color[k+2]
        list2.append(sum2)
        k = k+3
print(list2)
list2.sort()
myInt = 3
average2 = [x / myInt for x in list2]
```

Comment: Because you didn't reset `k` to 0 after the first loop.

Comment: `print(k)` just before the second loop to see your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have not reset `k` to 0. Before your 2nd loop, you need to do a `k=0` or else it will start at a point where it is already greater than the array length.